# How to get the userID of logged in user?

Tags: vb.net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim strsql As String = "select UserID from tGNLoginuser where userID=" & UserID
    UserID = DBH.getResult(strsql) ''library for executing query
    clearData()
End Sub
```

How to get the userid of loggedin user ?? is there any command for getting userID in windows forms

Comment: Are you using Login form

Comment: It depends where you stored the ID when the user logged to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get the logged in user name:

```
Environment.UserName
```

There is also:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent
```

Which returns a WindowsIdentity object that represents the current Windows user.

[WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Environment.UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)